# this bug is absurd: CSS backface-visibility not working on localhost?

Tags: css, webkit, localhost

this is weird:

same file test.html works then I double click it from

file:///Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test.html

but when I open

http://localhost/test.html

the CSS rules

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

is not working anymore... why??? what the heck? is not required any external file...the test.html has everything embedded in itself...this is weird

Comment: This is probably a silly suggestion, but did you try clearing your browser cache? Maybe the browser has old styles cached.

Comment: yes you are right, i did it and ti worked, but it dint on another project in the same browser, but now it works...totally random solution...still weird and unpredictable :(